# PHP script escapes special characters after switching servers, how to fix it?

Tags: php, escaping, special-characters

I have a primitive script that accepts a POST request (UTF-8 text) and sends an e-mail with it using `ob_start()`, `echo`, `ob_get_clean` and then `@mail`.

It worked perfectly until we switched servers, and now the text is modified - all special characters are escaped (`"` becomes `\"`, `\` -> `\\` and so on), and there are some extra spaces around certain character combinations (not sure why). I assume it's a matter of PHP configuration. How can I disable this escaping?

Comment: Sounds like magic quotes, what php version are you using?

Comment: @MKroeders: 5.3.29, it would seem.

Comment: Yup, that's magic quotes then. [Turn them off](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) or upgrade PHP to [a version that is still supported](http://php.net/downloads.php) (which will remove support for them).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I can Help you out.

It seems like the php.ini has magic_quotes turned on

It is supposed to be an obsolete option in php but it is not eliminated until php version 5.4.0.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

to Disable it, you can reconfigure php.ini like:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```